# Recover files from git objects

Tags: git

I would like to extract files in MI PC Suite Backup.

So, if I open the folder where backup is located `C:\Xiaomi\MiPhoneManager\Data\XXXXXX\` I have only a .git folder.

When I do a "git status", I see my files (pictures, apps, etc.). In Windows Explorer, the files are not presents.

[image: Screenshot of files in git status]

I don't know how to recover them.

I have used :

```
git read-tree --empty
git fsck --lost-found
```

These commands recover files in lost-found directory but without original filenames and no extensions.

A `git commit -m 'test'` give me this message: `fatal: index cache-tree records empty sub-tree`

Any ideas to recover them with original names? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout .`?

Comment: see if there are any active branches  with 'git branch'

Comment: Try a "git reset --hard HEAD" to reset your index and working tree? But any changes to tracked files are discarded.

Comment: @melpomene: i have messages like that "error: unknown file mode for /data/data/com.allocine.androidapp/databases/ in index" and now when I do "git status", I have : "fatal: internal error: ce_mode is 40771"

Comment: @DavidN: I have this message "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: Yup, figured that might be the case. Ok, good luck.